# C++ Morse to english

Tags: c++

So I have an assignment where I have to create a program that translates English text into morse code, and morse code to english text. So far I have done the English text to morse code and I am currently stuck on morse code to english text. I tried doing the same thing as the English to morse but I learned the hard way that it doesn't help, and I dont know where to start. I have been stuck like this for a long time, any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated please. So far I have this.

```
string Morse [arraysize] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..",".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---",
                   "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",
                   "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--",
                   "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", ".-.-.-",
                   "--..--", "..--.."};
string Letter [arraysize] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                    "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4",
                    "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "Stop", ",", "?"};

cout << "1 - Encode(Text to Morse)\n";
cout << "2 - Decode(Morse Code to Text)\n";
cout << "3 - Display the Morse Code\n";
cout << "4 - Quit\n\n";
cout << "Enter 1, 2, 3 or 4: ";
cin >> choice;


case 2:
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter a Coded Morse Message (e.g. .- -... -.-.)";
    cout << "\nSeparate Morse Code by blanks:\n";
    getline(cin,english);
    english2 = english;
    system("CLS");
    cout << "You entered:\n";
    cout << english;
    length1 = english.length();
    cout << "\n\nThe decoded message is:\n";
    for(int n = 0; n < length1+1; n++)
    {
         letter = english.at(n);
         if(letter != ' ')
         {
             for(int y = 0; y < 39; y++)
             {
                 string temp;
                 temp = toupper(letter);
                 if(temp == Morse[y])
                 {
                     cout << Letter[y];
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
    }
    cout << ".-.-.-\n";
    system("pause");
    english.erase();
    break;
```

Comment: Is each morse "letter" seperated by a delimeter? Morse code has not a fixed length code and is amgiguous. Maybe that's it.

Comment: Looks like there's some hold-over code from your English-to-Morse. For example, you're only looking at a single character in your `english` string when you need to be looking at a sub-string to get all the characters in the morse.

Comment: Read about `std::map`.

Comment: Why is what you have so far not correct? What specifically does not work? What are your expected results, and what are your actual results?

Comment: What is this `case 2:` doing outside of a `switch` statement? I've never seen it used like that before.

Comment: The case is outside the switch because I am only looking for help in this part, I don't want to display all the code.

Comment: What I am looking for is that if the user types in Morse code, it translate into English text, Ex: (User types in ) .... . .-.. .-.. ---, it translates into H E L L O

Comment: I appreciate the feedback guys but I realized I made a mistake on my part in the explanation. To my knowledge I can't use vector or maps because we haven't gone over that in my class. Also my teacher said it should be done in the main(), I guess we can only use strings for know and again I appreciate the feedback

Comment: *Also my teacher said it should be done in the main()* -- Why not functions to do those 4 different options?  Sticking everything in `main`, thus creating one gigantic `main` program, is not how proper programming should be taught.

Comment: @yes Removing extraneous code to focus on one part is good, but don't take it too far. There should still be enough context for the code to make sense. In this case, that probably means showing `int main() {` and either showing the `switch` or changing `case 2:` to a comment, perhaps `// Decode Morse code to text.` I would also suggest dropping most of the I/O. **For this question,** you do not need to show the menu, and you could simply set `english` to a string that does not decode properly -- no need to prompt the user for it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t notice you are not allowed to use maps (thanks, @Raymond). Here’s another solution.

1. **ASCII to Morse.** Instead of maps you may use a **look-up-table**. A LUT is an array whose indexes are the keys. In the case of character-to-Morse LUT the **key/index is the character**, the **value is the Morse-code**. Don’t forget that a character is actually a number (the OS is treating it in a different way, but still it is a number). `'A'` is `0x41` (`65 decimal`), so at index 65 of your table you will find `".-"` and so on. The entries which do not have associated a Morse-code will be set to zero.
2. **Morse to ASCII.** If you look at Morse-code as a **five symbols length code**, you will notice it needs three symbols to represent any letter: `A = .- = ***.-`, `B = -... = *-...` and so on. This means **any Morse symbol is a number written in base-3**: `.` is `1`, `-` is `2` and `*` is `0`. We can use this observation to generate another LUT. So, to convert from Morse to ASCII all you need is a **ternary converter** and a LUT.

Your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

const char* ascii_to_morse[] =
{
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  "-----", ".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.", // 0...9
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.",
  "---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..", // A...Z
};

const char morse_to_ascii[] =
{
  0, 'E', 'T', 0, 'I', 'A', 0, 'N', 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'S', 'U', 0, 'R', 'W', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'D', 'K',
  0, 'G', 'O', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'H', 'V', 0, 'F', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'L', 0, 0,
  'P', 'J', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'B', 'X', 0, 'C', 'Y', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Z', 'Q', 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '5', '4', 0, 0, '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  '6', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '7', 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '8', 0, 0, '9', '0',
};

int main()
{
  // ascii to morse test
  {
    ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\ascii.txt" };
    if (!is)
      return -1;

    ofstream os{ "c:\\temp\\morse.txt" };
    if (!os)
      return -2;

    // ascii to morse
    char c;
    while (is >> c)
      os << ascii_to_morse[c] << ' ';
  }

  // morse to ascii test
  {
    ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\morse.txt" };
    if (!is)
      return -1;

    ofstream os{ "c:\\temp\\ascii_check.txt" };
    if (!os)
      return -2;

    // morse to ascii
    string m;
    while (is >> m)
    {
      // convert m to index (ternary converter)
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < (int)m.length(); ++i)
      {
        int digit = m[i] == '.' ? 1 : 2;
        index = index * 3 + digit;
      }

      // look for the associated ascii code
      os << morse_to_ascii[index] << ' ';
    }
  }
}
```

**PREVIOUS SOLUTION:**

The simplest solution is, probably, a [`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

1. You can think of a map approximately the same way you are thinking about an array: you have an **index and a value associated to that index**. In a map the **key** (the equivalent of index) and the associated **value** can be anything: an integer, a character, a string, etc. For instance you can associate the string `".-"` to character `'A'`. Or you can do it the opposite direction: from `".-"` to `'A'`.
2. After you create the associations you can use the map **the same way you are using an array** (with some restrictions which do not concern you for now)
3. Another idea would be to convert the Morse code to a base-3 number and use a **look-up-table**.

Your **fixed program** (note that lower-case letters are not taken into account and the input is assumed to be valid):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// http://www.csgnetwork.com/morsecodechrtbl.html
map< char, string > ascii_to_morse =
{
{'A',".-"},
{'B',"-..."},
{'C',"-.-."},
{'D',"-.."},
{'E',"."},
{'F',"..-."},
{'G',"--."},
{'H',"...."},
{'I',".."},
{'J',".---"},
{'K',"-.-"},
{'L',".-.."},
{'M',"--"},
{'N',"-."},
{'O',"---"},
{'P',".--."},
{'Q',"--.-"},
{'R',".-."},
{'S',"..."},
{'T',"-"},
{'U',"..-"},
{'V',"...-"},
{'W',".--"},
{'X',"-..-"},
{'Y',"-.--"},
{'Z',"--.."},
{'0',"-----"},
{'1',".----"},
{'2',"..---"},
{'3',"...--"},
{'4',"....-"},
{'5',"....."},
{'6',"-...."},
{'7',"--..."},
{'8',"---.."},
{'9',"----."},
{'.',".-.-.-"},
{',',"--..--"},
{'?',"..--.."},
{'=',"-...-"},
};

map< string, char > morse_to_ascii;

int main()
{
  // build the reversed map
  for (auto kv : ascii_to_morse)
    morse_to_ascii[kv.second] = kv.first;

  // ascii to morse test
  {
    ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\ascii.txt" };
    if (!is)
      return -1;

    ofstream os{ "c:\\temp\\morse.txt" };
    if (!os)
      return -2;

    // ascii to morse
    char c;
    while (is >> c)
      os << ascii_to_morse[c] << ' ';
  }

  // morse to ascii test
  {
    ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\morse.txt" };
    if (!is)
      return -1;

    ofstream os{ "c:\\temp\\ascii_check.txt" };
    if (!os)
      return -2;

    // morse to ascii
    string m;
    while (is >> m)
      os << morse_to_ascii[m] << ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: OP said in the comment he can not use maps or vectors.

Comment: @Raymond I didn't notice this in the post. It must be somewhere in comments.

Comment: @ZDF sorry about not explaining my problem to well, it's my first time posting. Thank you for the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For no use of **maps or vectors**.

You might use a simple dynamic array to add each character converted to the array. Then use a `for-loop` to convert back to English each morse sequence. You loop through the string you need to convert while the counter is less than the `string.length();`.

Here is an example using only the letters a,b,c and it is **not** case-sensitive. But notice how the size of the array commented out is **3**, we only are testing 3 or fewer characters, make sure to use a dynamic array. You see I set the size with `string.length();`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // Test sentence
  std::string sentence = "abc";
  // Removed, you could test with std::string morse[3]
  // Dynamic array set to the size of the length sentence
  auto *morse = new std::string[sentence.length()];

  // Loop through each character of the sentence,
  // increment the position counter, store the value
  // in the array
  int position = 0;
  for (auto &c : sentence)
    {
      if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
        {
          std::cout << ".-";
          morse[position++] = (".-");
        }
      if (c == 'b' || c == 'B')
        {
          std::cout << "-...";
          morse[position++] = ("-...");
        }

      if (c == 'c' || c == 'C')
        {
          std::cout << "-.-.";
          morse[position++] = ("-.-.");
        }
    }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // Loop through the array, and convert
  // each morse sequence back, for loop
  // loops based on the size of the position
  for (int i = 0; i < position; i++)
    {
      if (morse[i] == ".-")
        std::cout << 'A';
      if (morse[i] == "-...")
        std::cout << 'B';
      if (morse[i] == "-.-.")
        std::cout << 'C';
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can opt in for switch statement for example

```
 string wordsToMorse(string name)
       {
        switch(name){
         case 'a':
         case 'A'
           return '.-';
         case 'b':
         case 'B':
           return '-...';
   // and so on
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string>Morse {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..",".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---",
                   "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",
                   "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--",
                   "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", ".-.-.-",
                   "--..--", "..--.."};
vector<string>Letter {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                    "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4",
                    "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "Stop", ",", "?"};

int main()
{
    string morse_code;

    cout << "Enter a Coded Morse Message (e.g. .- -... -.-.)";
    cout << "\nSeparate Morse Code by blanks:\n";
    getline(cin,morse_code);
    cout << "You entered:\n";
    cout << morse_code;
    cout << "\n\nThe decoded message is:\n";

    stringstream mors(morse_code);
    string letter;

    while (mors >> letter) {
        vector<string>::iterator it;
        it = find(Morse.begin(), Morse.end(), letter);
        size_t dist = distance(Morse.begin(), it);
        cout << Letter[dist] << endl;
    }


}
```